# Having problem to "count()" functions in laravel. Please help me to fix this

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table named 'runs' and there is a column named 'round'. In this column it will have 3 rounds : first, ko and final. But after using count() when i dd this it will shows the result as '2'.[image: See the image]

```
$rounds = DB::table('runs')->groupBy('round')->count();

dd($rounds)
```

Comment: Can you send the dd() without count() ? To see the records.

Comment: I,m sorry i didn't get you. I edited the post put the image of dd($rounds). Can you please see that.

Comment: Please, without count(), to see all records.

Comment: i just want to retrieve that how many types of data in the round. Which answer should be 3. Don't want to retrieve all the records.

Comment: `count()` returns the group count. than means there are two groups in the result.

Comment: then can you help me too getting the appropriate results???????

Comment: yes, i solved that problem using mysql ``SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT round) from fees``

Answer (score 1):

count() after GroupBy count groups.
May be in your runs table you don't have rows with the 3 rounds (one of these rounds doesn't appear in runs table).